# Vectors - the sign of the coefficient?

Tags: vectors

If we have two vectors, which we know have the relation:

$$r_1=-Br_2$$

Where B is a positive constant.

Then I believe we can say that:

$$|r_2|=|\frac{r_1}{-B}|$$

I thought that the magnitudes would then have the following relation:

$$|r_2|=\frac{|r1|}{B}$$

However, it is suggested in the exercises I have been doing that:

$$|r_2|=\frac{|r1|}{-B}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: The last equality is wrong (unless $r_1$ and $r_2$ are null): $|r_2|$ must be non-negative.

Comment: It is possible that $(-B)$ is the positive number and that $B$ is the negative number if the last line was indeed intentional.

Comment: Yes, its the statement that was implied by an answer in my workbook. I think that it is incorrect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnitudes are never negative, so your last equation can only be right if $B$ is always negative. At any rate, the precise statement of what we can conclude from that relation is:

$$
|r_2| = \frac{|r_1|}{|B|}
$$

If $B$ is a positive constant, then $|B| = B$.

(This is because $\left|\alpha \mathbf{v}\right| = |\alpha||\mathbf{v}|$, i.e. passing through the vector magnitude turns a scalar into its absolute value).